Plotting more than one curve in one plot using parametric plot option
A follow up to the previous question.
The function circp[x,y,t] below is used to plot a curve (circle or ellipse) at different position in a single plot as shown
circp[x_, y_, t_] := Module[{eox, eoy, con, ex, ey, out, phase},
  eox = 2*x;
  eoy = 2*y;
  con = Sqrt[eox^2 + eoy^2];
  phase = Arg[eox] - Arg[eoy];
  ex = (eox*Cos[t])/con;
  ey = (-eoy*Sin[t + phase])/con;
  out = {x, y} + {ex, ey}]

plot = ParametricPlot[{circp[1, 1, t], circp[1, 3, t], circp[1, 5, t],
    circp[3, 1, t], circp[3, 3, t], circp[3, 5, t]}, {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  Frame -> True]


But now if i try to make a table it does not work. I get blank plot. I tried like this:
data = Table[circp[x, y, t], {x, 1, 3, 2}, {y, 1, 3, 2}];
 newplot = ParametricPlot[Flatten[data, 1], {t, 0, 2*Pi}]

Also i need the spacing between each curve to be same.

It works, but you need to use same number of circles and also use Evaluate to get the coloring. Also added Frame->True
 data = Table[circp[x, y, t], {x, 1, 3, 2}, {y, 1, 5, 2}]
newplot = ParametricPlot[Evaluate@Flatten[data, 1], {t, 0, 2*Pi}, 
  Frame -> True]



I get blank plot. I tried like this:

This is strange. I do not get blank plot. But the plot I get is not the the same your first Plot. I am using V 14
